# Sticky Headers on JavaFX Gridpane

Tags: javafx-8, sticky, gridpane

I was wondering if there is a possibility to implement Sticky Headers on a GridPane in JavaFX, meaning a row of the GridPane that stays in place while you can scroll through the remaining rows of the pane.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't use a `TableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to ensure the header nodes are the last children of the `GridPane.children` list. This allows you to set the `translateY` property of the header nodes to remain at the top of the `ScrollPane` wrapping the `GridPane`:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();

// fill grid
Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.LIGHTGREEN, Color.LIGHTBLUE};
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    grid.add(new Rectangle(50, 50, colors[(2 * i - 2) % colors.length]), 0, i);
    grid.add(new Label(Integer.toString(2 * i - 1)), 0, i);
    grid.add(new Rectangle(50, 50, colors[(2 * i - 1) % colors.length]), 1, i);
    grid.add(new Label(Integer.toString(2 * i)), 1, i);
}

// create & add header
Node[] headers = new Node[] {
    createHeaderNode("H1"),
    createHeaderNode("H2")
};
grid.addRow(0, headers);

ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(grid);
scrollPane.setPrefHeight(400);

// keep header in position on top of the viewport
InvalidationListener headerUpdater = o -> {
    final double ty = (grid.getHeight() - scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight()) * scrollPane.getVvalue();
    for (Node header : headers) {
        header.setTranslateY(ty);
    }
};
grid.heightProperty().addListener(headerUpdater);
scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(headerUpdater);
scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(headerUpdater);
```

```
private static Label createHeaderNode(String text) {
    Label label = new Label(text);
    label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    label.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-background-color: white;");
    return label;
}
```

Comment: You are a genuis @fabian